Docker Compose default environment variable substitution
docker-compose.yml:
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:latest
        env_file:
            -   .env
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PORT="${POSTGRES_PORT:-5078}"
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
            - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
            - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
        expose:
            - "$POSTGRES_PORT"
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "/usr/bin/pg_isready", "-d", "$POSTGRES_DB", "-U", "$POSTGRES_USER", "-p", "$POSTGRES_PORT" ]
            interval: 15s
            timeout: 60s
            retries: 5
            start_period: 40s

    api:
        restart: always
        build:
            context: ./api
            target: base
        command: >
            bash -c "./manage.py migrate &&
                 ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./api/apps:/code/apps
            - ./api/config:/code/config
            - ./api/docs:/code/docs
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
            postgres:
                condition: service_healthy

My .env file doesn't define a port for Postgres, which is why I'm trying to add the default value for when it's not given, as shown in https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/variable-interpolation/#interpolation-syntax. Whenever I build the image for the api service, I get the warning WARN[0000] The "POSTGRES_PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. Having the value printed out also shows it to be empty. How should I properly set the default value?
(Edit, here's the .env file)
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-defaultpasswordhere}
POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB:-defaultdbnamehere}
POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER:-defaultusernamehere}


Hope your env has ${POSTGRES_PORT} has it set.
Can you double check that

I'm trying to have the docker-compose.yml file set the default for when POSTGRES_PORT isn't in the .env file.

ok. But if you check the documentation, you can see
${VAR:-default} -> value of VAR if set and non-empty, otherwise default

Right, and since I have not set the value, it should use the default of 5078. However, it ends up as an empty variable.

Because when you use colon, it expects an non-empty value. Just remove the colon from the declaration. It should work.

I tried POSTGRES_PORT="${POSTGRES_PORT-5078}" but I'm still getting the warning WARN[0000] The "POSTGRES_PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.

Can you please do the cat .env and share the POSTGRES rletaed details, by masking your password.

If you check the docker-compose documentation, you can see,
In case of ${POSTGRES_PORT:-5078} expression, value of POSTGRES_PORT has to be set and non-empty, otherwise default`
You better try the below syntax.
Use ${POSTGRES_PORT-5078} intead of ${POSTGRES_PORT:-5078} , removing the colon.
